# How to form a query to find all records whose id is present in some list, for example [1, 3, 10]?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

How to use .nest NEST in Elasticsearch to form a query like: select * from tbl where tbl.id in [1, 3, 10] ? Or in other words, how to form a query to find all records whose id is present in some list, for example [1, 3, 10]?

Comment: How does your current elastic document schema looks like ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below ElasticSearch query for searching on document `_id` field.

```json
POST index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": ["1","2","3"]
    }
  }
}
```

Below is equivalent .Net code.

```
var ids = new long[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var multiGetResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Index("index1")
    .Query(q => q
        .Ids(i => i
            .Values(ids)
        )
    )
);
```

If you are storing `id` in separate field in ElasticSearch document then you can use below query:

```json
POST index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id": ["1","2","3"]
    }
  }
}
```

Below is equivalent .Net code.

```
client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
        .Index("index1")
        .Query(q => q      
            .Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Name).Terms(ids))      
        )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to achieve your use-case, in JSON it would look like below.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tbl.id": [ 1,2,4 ],
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```